# Diagrams/Infographics for learning about Computer Science/Programming

Tags: computer-science, diagrams

A few friends and I are doing a self-study on Computer Science/Programming and taking the Computer Science AP A exam. Although I have experience in programming in a few languages, it's still difficult for me to explain some concepts such as OOP and memory management.

Are there are interesting diagrams or infographics that could explain these things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like the course material that MIT puts online for free, the video lectures in the intro-cs class should be useful.

http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/